# Warning: [W108] The rule-based lemmatizer did not find POS annotation for the token 'This'

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

What this message is about? How do I remove this warning message?

```py
import scispacy
import spacy
import en_core_sci_lg
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.tokens import Doc


def create_lang_detector(nlp, name):
    return LanguageDetector()


Language.factory("language_detector", func=create_lang_detector)
nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load(disable=["tagger", "ner"])
nlp.max_length = 2000000
nlp.add_pipe('language_detector', last=True)

doc = nlp('This is some English text. Das ist ein Haus. This is a house.')
```

> Warning:
>
> [W108] The rule-based lemmatizer did not find POS annotation for the token 'This'. Check that your pipeline includes components that assign token.pos, typically 'tagger'+'attribute_ruler' or 'morphologizer'.
>
> [W108] The rule-based lemmatizer did not find POS annotation for the token 'is'. Check that your pipeline includes components that assign token.pos, typically 'tagger'+'attribute_ruler' or 'morphologizer'.
>
> [W108] The rule-based lemmatizer did not find POS annotation for the token 'some'. Check that your pipeline includes components that assign token.pos, typically 'tagger'+'attribute_ruler' or 'morphologizer'.
> .
> .
> .
> .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The lemmatizer is a separate component from the tagger in spacy v3. Disable the lemmatizer along with the tagger to avoid these warnings:

```py
nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load(disable=["tagger", "ner", "lemmatizer"])
```